# How to make Liferay control panel fields like Web-Content's Description a mandatory input field?

Tags: java, liferay

I want to make some fields in control panel mandatory. Whenever someone creates a new Web-Content, Structure or a Template, i want it not to be saved until the user has added some text in the description and other fields. Also i want to be able to do a grammar check of the text written in these fields. I think i probably have to use some web-services to do that. Is there anything out-of-box from Liferay to achieve this? If i have to write code, Would i be creating a hook? I want to do this on Liferay 6.1. Thank you.[image]
Example: Make the description field as a required field in the this screen-shot, just like the name is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever someone creates a new Web-Content, Structure or a Template, i want it not to be saved until the user has added some text in the description and other fields.

If you are creating web-contents from the structure/template, Liferay does provide the option i.e. **Required** while creating fields in **Structure** to make them compulsory while publishing the web-content.

Is this what you are looking for?? If not, Please provide a practice example.

EDIT :

**Option 1** : Create a "Structure" with a Fields "Description" with type HTML, and make it **Required**. Add web-content with of newly created structure.
**Option 2** : Create a "Hook" to add validation for basic default web-content

**For Grammar Check** :
Plz look at following link : [SCAYT and CKEditor in Liferay portal 6] https://www.liferay.com/web/jonas.yuan/blog/-/blogs/scayt-and-ckeditor-in-liferay-portal-6

Hope this helps.

Comment: In Control Panel, When a user adds a new Web-Content, He has to provide a name and description of it. While name is a required field, description is not. I am trying to make description as a required field as well. Also I want to do the spell check and grammar check of the text that has been input in the description field. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Aston. Any idea how i can find the jsp that i need to customize?

Comment: I have added a screen-shot to make my question more understandable.

Comment: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/46636427... may be this will help you...

Comment: Thanks Aston, that helped. Furthermore, I was able to make description as a required field following - https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/39663934 and adding                       `<aui:input name="description">
 <aui:validator name="required" />
 <aui:validator name="alphanum" />
 <aui:validator name="minLength">20</aui:validator>
</aui:input>`                                                                                               in html/portlet/journal/edit_structure.jsp

Comment: Glad it helped. Mark it as answer, if you like. Up vote would be appreciated.